# CSS Center Div - Problems

Tags: css, layout, html

I am currently working on a simple site but i need to centre a div in the middle of the screen that will adapt to different browser sizes.

I have nearly got it to work but not quite could someone instruct me where I am going wrong.
The live site to look at is  http://adamnicolaou.com/

Thanks for the help

heres my css:

```
/* DEFAULTS
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
* { font-family:FuturaFont; color:#F1F2F2; background-color:#333133; }
/* FONT - TEXT
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
@font-face { font-family:FuturaFont; src: url('../font/FuturaLT_Light.ttf'),                  url('../font/FuturaLT_Light.eot'); /* IE9 */ }
* { font-family:FuturaFont, helvetica; color:#F1F2F2; background-color:#333133; letter-spacing:2px;}
h5 { font-size:25px; text-transform:uppercase; text-align:center; margin-top:5px; }
h1 { font-size:20px; text-transform:uppercase; }
p { font-size: 18px; letter-spacing:3px; text-transform:uppercase; }
h4 { font-size:18px; text-transform:uppercase; line-height:25px;}
footer small { font-size: 12px; text-transform:none; text-align: center;  }

/* LAYOUT
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
html, body, #container { height:97.5%; margin: 0; padding: 0; padding-bottom:-8%;}
body { min-width:1164px; min-height:720px;}
#container { height: auto; min-height: 98%; margin:auto 0; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; position:relative; }
#content { padding-bottom: 10px; margin-left:135px;  margin-top:60px; width:900px; position:relative; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; }
footer {   font-size:15px; text-align:center; height:20px; position:relative; }
#enter { vertical-align:middle; position:relative; margin-top:5%; padding:0; }
header { padding-left:10px; padding-right:10px; background-color:transparent; }
aside { margin-left:520px; position:relative; margin-top:-530px;}

/* LINKS - NAVIGATION - HEADER
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
a { text-decoration:none; border:0px; padding:0; }
a:hover { text-decoration:underline; }
#nav ul { list-style:none; text-align:right; text-transform:uppercase; padding-right:10px; line-height:32px; position:relative; margin-top:-130px; font-size:20px;  }
#logo { padding:10px;  position:relative; z-index:10;}
.navtext { margin-top:-62px; margin-left:160px; z-index:10; position:relative; background-color:transparent; width:800px; }
body#home ul li .home, body#design ul li .design, body#photography ul li .photography,      body#contact ul li .contact { text-decoration:underline; }
#content a .imglink:hover { border:3px; border-style:solid; color:#626162; }

/* PORTFOLIO IMAGES
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#content .img { padding:10px; position:relative; }
```

and heres my HTML Code for the front page:

```
<body id="index">
    <div id="container">
        <header>
            <div id="nav">
            </div> <!--- END OF NAV DIV --->
        </header>
        <div id="enter">
            <center><img src="images/enter_logo.png"><br></center><br><br>
            <a href="welcome"><h5>Enter</h5></a>
        </div>
    </div> <!--- END OF CONTAINER DIV --->
</body>
```

Comment: Uh, you're missing a whole lotta ending comment tags there, mister... :p

Comment: Okay, maybe just one, before the Apple Touch icon `<link>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

if you are looking for a vertical centering, try this in your CSS rule:

```
#outer {
    position:static;
}
#middle {
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
}
#inner {
    position:absolute;
    top:-50%;
}
```

you can check it out in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7Nxvg/)

just resize the window and see how it looks